# How to run javascript unit tests on django templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, testing, jestjs

I am trying to create a django application that has javascript functions. Some of these functions also uses JQuery. I want to write unit tests for these functions using Jest.

**index.html**

```
<script src="{% static 'jquery-3.5.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'setup.js' %}"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(async function(){
        const data = await myFunction()
    })
</script>
```

**setup.js**

```
async function myFunction(){
    // call some jquery function here
    const res = await $.ajax()
    return res
}
```

**setup.test.js**

```
import {myFunction} from '../setup'

test('test my function', async () => {
    await myFunction()
})
```

I have two problems here.

- When I call my function in my django template it works, but when I run the test it does not since it won't recognize jquery.
- I cannot import my function in the test unless I do

  ```
  export async function myFunction(){
      // call some jquery function here
      const res = await $.ajax()
      return res
  }
  ```

  however, this won't work in my index.html because "expected token 'export' at ..."

I have tried adding this to my **base.html**, however I get "Cannot use import statement outside a module at ..."

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(async function(){
        import myFunction from '{% static "setup.js" %}'
        const data = await myFunction()
    })
</script>
```

I have also tried **setup.test.js**

```
jest.mock('jquery')
import $ from "jquery"
import {myFunction} from '../setup'

jest.mock('jquery', () => ({ajax: jest.fn()}))

test('test my function', async () => {
    await myFunction()
})
```

Not too sure if my syntax is correct, but I am getting "$.ajax" is not a function in setup.js